# What does "4M" mean in a context of politics?

Tags: tiempo, siglas, jerga-política

What does "4M" mean in the headline I have clipped here? I keep seeing it but don't know how to look up what it means.

> Iglesias, confirmado por las bases como candidato de Podemos el 4M
>
> [image: candidato de Podemos el 4M]

Comment: It talks about the month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

4M stands for '4 de mayo', and in this case it refers to the date when the [Madrilenian regional election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Madrilenian_regional_election) in Spain will be held: May 4th, 2021. So the capital letter corresponds to the initial letter of the month.

In Spanish we tend to use these acronyms for dates, so it is easier to refer to them once they've become quite known among the readers of that field.

Some of these acronyms are still famous:

- 11M: [Atentados del 11 de marzo de 2004](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atentados_del_11_de_marzo_de_2004)
- 15M: [Movimiento 15-M](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movimiento_15-M)
- ...

Whereas others have a limited time life and end up vanishing after the event is over.

Comment: Good thing only one month starts with M...

Comment: @ikegami March and May...

Comment: @FairOPShotgun March starts with M, while May starts with M.

Comment: @ikegami Better than going by what the last letters are.

Comment: @FairOPShotgun, yup, that's the one!

Comment: The OP might be interested in the list in https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numer%C3%B3nimo

Comment: @mdewey good to know it is called _numerónimo_! Many are unknown to me, while others are missing. Such lists vary all the time, since they vanish regularly. Only time says which are to persist, and this also depends a lot on the place and background of the people involved.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' at least your notation is unambiguous. We do not know whether 9/11 is S11 (US) or N9 (UK). Sighs.

Comment: So how do you differentiate between March and May if they both use M?

Comment: @Bluelion7 good question! These numeronyms become so known that people just know them. The date itself is not important, but the moment they refer to.

Comment: «Que la fuerza te acompañe» May the force be with you... #StarWarsDay